# Is it possible to access instance of exception "catched" with JUnit Rule ExpectedException?

Tags: java, exception, junit, assert, rules

Suppose that in a test is:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();
```

and some test contains:

```
thrown.expect(SomeNastyException.class);
```

Now if there is a need to inspect this `SomeNastyException` more detailed what would be the way?

Of course it would be possible just not to use `ExcpectedException` and wrap call with **try/catch** and then inspect the exception in any way it is needed but now question is about can it be done with `ExpectedException`, something like:

```
assertEquals("42", thrown.getException().getUniversalAnswerToEverything());
```

Comment: Not simply; the rule is there basically as syntactic sugar exactly for this. This is one of many reasons I strongly prefer Spock over plain JUnit.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-, you can expect a particular exception with a message or a cause in JUnit. By using `expect(Matcher<?>)` override. There is no advantage Spock has over JUnit in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a less specialized version of `expect` method in that rule, that accepts a Hamcrest's matcher:

[expect(Matcher)](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#expect(org.hamcrest.Matcher))

This method would allow you to assert almost anything about the thrown exception, provided there is a `Matcher` implementation for that.

For instance, for your case it'd look something like this:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasProperty;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

....

exceptions.expect(hasProperty("UniversalAnswerToEverything", is(42)));
```

Hamcrest has a pretty flexible matcher model, so you can also easily write your own if you aren't satisfied with what's inlucded in the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hasProperty hamcrest Matcher. And if your SomeNastyException does not conform to java bean protocol, you can create a custom hamcrest matcher for your exception:

```
package stackoverflow.q59946794;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.FeatureMatcher;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
import org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SomeNastyExceptionSpec {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeNastyExceptionSpec.class.getName());

    public static class SomeNastyException extends Exception implements java.io.Serializable {
        SomeNastyException(String message) { super(message);}
        public Integer getUniversalAnswerToEverything() {return 42;}
    }

    public static Matcher<SomeNastyException> hasUniversalAnswerToEverythingFeature(final int expectedAnswer) {
        return new FeatureMatcher<SomeNastyException, Integer>(
                new IsEqual<Integer>(expectedAnswer),
                "SomeNastyException actual answer",
                "SomeNastyException expected answer"
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Integer featureValueOf(SomeNastyException actual) {
                return actual.getUniversalAnswerToEverything();
            }
        };

    }
    public static Matcher<SomeNastyException> hasUniversalAnswerToEverything(final int expectedAnswer) {
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<SomeNastyException>() {

            @Override
            protected void describeMismatchSafely(SomeNastyException e, Description description) {
                description.appendText("was ").appendValue(e.getUniversalAnswerToEverything());
            }

            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("SomeNastyException with answer ").appendValue(expectedAnswer);
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(SomeNastyException e) {
                return e.getUniversalAnswerToEverything() == expectedAnswer;
            }
        };
    }

    @Rule(order = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void shouldTestExceptionMessage() throws Exception {
        thrown.expect(SomeNastyException.class);
        thrown.expect(hasUniversalAnswerToEverything(42));
        thrown.expect(hasUniversalAnswerToEverythingFeature(42));
        thrown.expectMessage("always 42");
        throw new SomeNastyException("always 42");
    }
}
```

Comment: `FeatureMatcher` is a lot better for this.

Answer (score 0):

My question was asked while still using JUnit4. Recently migrated to JUnit5 and it has exactly what I was looking for, namely `assertThrows` that returns the exception thrown. As a dummy example:

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void testThrows() {
    Exception exception = assertThrows(NotAnswerableException.class, () -> {
        throw new NotAnswerableException("please rephrase your question", param2, param3);
    });
    assertTrue(exception.getMessage().startsWith("please"));
    assertEquals(param2, exception.getParam2());
}
```